# Create empty truecolor PNG with ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, png

How can I create an empty (transparent) PNG containing 24 bit color channels with ImageMagick? The obvious one

```
    convert -size 1920x1080 xc:transparent blank.png
```

will create an 1bit b/w image with alpha channel. Adding some options like

```
convert -size 1920x1080 xc:transparent  -colorspace rgb  -type truecolor blank.png
```

which work for .jpg format, still gains the same 1bit result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ImageMagick defines several "sub-formats" for PNG that can be used to request the encoder to write a particular PNG color-type and bit-depth.  By 24-bit I assume you mean 8-bit red, green, and blue channels; for that use the png24 subformat:

```
convert -size 1920x1080 xc:transparent png24:blank.png
```

Note that "xc:transparent" creates an image with an alpha channel, which will be conveyed in a PNG24 via a PNG tRNS chunk.  If you don't want that, then specify a non-transparent color such as "xc:white" instead.

Other possibilities are png8 (8-bit indexed with binary transparency), png32 (8-bit-per-channel RGBA), png48 (16-bit-per channel RGB), and png64 (16-bit-per-channel RGBA).

Type

```
convert -list format | grep PNG
```

to see what's available in your ImageMagick installation.

Comment: Ah cool. So the internal color format is actually not used, but the selection is made by the output format. The `png24:` worked well for me. Thanks!